# Alternative/ How to use {% url %} in django 1.8?

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django on version 1.8.

In their [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/) they suggest to use `{% url %}` template tag in order to avoid hardcoding the url. But it is not working in the v1.8, and confirmed that it is deprecated in this version.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Does anyone know any alternative ?

Update:
p_index.html

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for que in latest_question_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' que.id %}">{{ que.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p> No polls questions are availabe. </p>
{% endif %}
```

Above code gives me this error: `'str' object has no attribute 'regex'`

**When I change the href line as below, works fine!**

```
<li><a href="/polls/{{ que.id }}/">{{ que.question_text }}</a></li>
```

urlpatterns in polls app:

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.index, name='view_index'),

    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<q_no>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<q_no>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<q_no>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),

]
```

The main urls.py is as below :

```
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', 'home.views.index'),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace = 'polls')),
    url(r'^android/start', 'testpage.views.androidStart'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

]
```

Comment: The syntax is **not** deprecated. Only the `'path.to.some_view'` dotted path syntax to specify the view is deprecated.

Comment: You'll need to show how you are using it exactly, the syntax as documented works *just fine*.

Comment: Please post the full traceback of `'str' object has no attribute 'regex'`.

Comment: Thanks all!, Today morning I restarted and its working fine!, I still didn't figure out why I was getting rendering error !! Anyway since Wtower helped me to understand it better, I'm going to accept his ans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got this wrong. The `{% url %}` tag is not depercated to my best of knowledge, and I have never heard of any alternative. What is deprecated is the syntax to pass a dotted Python path:

> **Deprecated since version 1.8:**
>
> You can also pass a dotted Python path to a view function, but this syntax is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10:
>
> ```
> {% url 'path.to.some_view' v1 v2 %}
> ```

Comment: Hi, Thanks!, I updated the question with code sections. Can you please tell me what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Welcome! Have you gat a namespace specified in your main urls.py? (Not the urls.py of your app).

Comment: ya, i have the namespace like this :  url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace = 'polls')),             also noted that same error happens with "{% url 'polls:detail' que.id %}"    Anyway I dont have multiple apps with same name for url

Comment: Then `{% url 'detail' que.id %}` should be `{% url 'polls:detail' que.id %}`.

Comment: Even though i don't have any other url with the same name assigned, I checked `{% url 'polls:detail' que.id %}`. Same error during template rendering..